# Google Sign In within embedded browsers (Messenger, Instagram) not working.. Googles webview policy?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, oauth

I have a Nextjs web app with Firebase Auth. I only allow my users to login with Google.

All my traffic is coming from social media apps which have an embedded browser. So on launch day I learned that signing in only works directly from a browser like chrome or safari but not within a webview within an application. This is a nightmare.

I tried switching from signInWithPopUp() to signInWithRedirect(), but still same issue.

error 403: disallowed_useragent

This app doesn't comply with Googles webview policy.

[image]

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: If you have come up with a solution feel free to write an answer as I'm dealing with similar problem